# Erro al conectar mysql con xampp

Tags: xampp

Tengo que usar java con mysql entonces necesito apache y mysql. He instalado XAMP y apache no da error pero mysql no me conecta.
Los puerto 80 a 8080 y el 430 a 4430 ya lo he probado y no sirve.

El cambiar de puerto el mysql desde my.ini de 3306 a 3307 o a 33060 tambien lo he probado y tampoco rula. Os dejo el erro que da.

```
> >     Problem detected! 9:57:25  [mysql]  Port 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"! 9:57:25  [mysql]  MySQL WILL NOT start without the
> configured ports free! 9:57:25  [mysql]   You need to
> uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application 9:57:25 
> [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a
> different port 9:57:25  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
> 9:57:25  [mysql]  Status change detected: running 9:57:29  [mysql]
>   Status change detected: stopped 9:57:29  [mysql]    Error: MySQL
> shutdown unexpectedly. 9:57:29  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked
> port, missing dependencies,  9:57:29  [mysql]     improper privileges, a
> crash, or a shutdown by another method. 9:57:29  [mysql]  Press the
> Logs button to view error logs and check 9:57:29  [mysql]     the Windows
> Event Viewer for more clues 9:57:29  [mysql]  If you need more help,
> copy and post this 9:57:29  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

y este es lo que pone el archivo logs

```
> 2019-05-07 09:57:25 c78 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2019-05-07  9:57:25 3192 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2019-05-07  9:57:25 3192 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2019-05-07  9:57:25 3192 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2019-05-07  9:57:25 3192 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-05-07  9:57:25 3192 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2019-05-07  9:57:25 3192 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-05-07  9:57:25 3192 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2019-05-07  9:57:25 3192 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2019-05-07  9:57:25 3192 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-05-07  9:57:25 3192 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-05-07  9:57:26 3192 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-05-07  9:57:26 3192 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-05-07  9:57:26 3192 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.43-84.3 started; log sequence number 1835087
2019-05-07  9:57:26 4616 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2019-05-07  9:57:26 3192 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-05-07  9:57:26 3192 [ERROR] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: unknown option '--by default).'
2019-05-07  9:57:26 3192 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a entrar al cmd como Administrador, introduce el comando `netstat -aon` y localiza el proceso que tenga el puerto que este usando MySQL, a través del Administrador de Tareas, si no es un proceso importante, buscalo por su `PID` y finalizalo, ahora podrás iniciar el servicio.

Comment: segun tasklist ese puerto lo ocupa mysqDl.exe pero si no me deja iniciarlo no entinedo jaja

Comment: Pues segun tu XAMPP hay otro, en la lista que te devuelve el comando tiene que haber mas de un registro con ese puerto en escucha pero tendran distinto PID, vuelve a buscar.

Comment: NADA SOLO el 3008 que corresponde a mysqld.exe

Comment: Pues lo he arreglado miles de veces asi, revisa si en mas sitios de la configuracion de MySQL tienes que cambiar el puerto de escucha.

Comment: He cambiado en todo los sitios donde venia el 3306 a mano buscando con el buscador

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que sw debe cambiar el puerto en el archivo de configuración de mysql y de apache también.
Osea si en el archivo de configuración de my sql pusiste 3307 debes ir al al archivo de configuración de phpmyadmin y buscar el anterior puerto que tenía ejemplo 3306 y reemplazarlo por el 3307.

Espero sirva.